# Rspec, can you stub a method that doesn't exist on an object (or mock an object that can take any method)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, stub

This might sound like a terribly basic question... so let me explain the context. I'm retrieving an event from Stripe, but for the purposes of this, but this works for other things that I've considered.

The data that I need in the Stripe object is way buried, so I'd have to do `event.data.object.date.lines.first.id`. I'm not sure how to mock/stub this...

The only way I can think to do this is create a fake model that simulates a Stripe event object (in this example for me, keep in mind that Stripe events can't be user created). And then I can mock that fake model. But is that really the way to do it? Is there some way I can just use Rspec to stub the whole shebang and say that `event.data.object.date.lines.first.id` wherever it appears should just retun `1`?

Oh and also... if not, and it turns out I do have to create a fake model... tips greatly appreciated, because right now I'm thinking this "Fake" model needs many layers of children, and is totally not worth the time investment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSpec provides no special mechanisms to access elements under test, so yes, you would need to somehow `stub` the `id` method and have it return whatever you wish (e.g. `1`).

To do that, you must have a way to access the `event` object in your test so that you can stub it's `data` method. Once you can access to it, then you can use RSpec's `receive_message_chain` matcher to specify the sequence of methods for which, if called, you will return `1`.

If there is some public `Strip` method you can mock to return a `double` for event, that would be the most straightforward approach.

If that's not possible, you could determine the class of `event` and use the `allow_any_instance_of` method to stub it's `data` method. The resulting mock would be as follows, assuming `Foo` was the class of the `event` object you're concerned about:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Foo)).to receive_message_chain(
  :data, :object, :date, :lines, :first, :id).and_return(1)
```

Here's a test that passes:

```
module Stripe
  class Event ; end
end
describe 'stack overflox example' do
  it 'should pass' do
    event = Stripe::Event.new
    expect(event).to receive_message_chain(:data, :object, :date, :lines, :first, :id).and_return(23)
    expect(event.data.object.date.lines.first.id).to eq(23)
  end
end
```

Comment: So I'd have to go with option 2. Class of event = `Stripe::Event`. If I try `allow(any_instance_of(Stripe::Event)).to receive_message_chain(:data, :object, :date).and_return(Date.today)`, I get `undefined method `any_instance_of' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::HooksController::IfGoodJSONIsReceived::WhenEventCanBeFound::WhenPlanCanBeFound::WhenIncrementAndSaveAreSuccessful::WhenStripeInvoiceNumberIs4IECameFrom3:0x007fc958dabcd0>`. And if I try, `Stripe::Event.any_instance.stub_chain(:data, :object, :date).and_return(Date.today)`, I get `Stripe::Event does not implement #data`

Comment: Sorry, I'd mixed old and new RSpec methods. I've updated the answer to reflect the current method., That said, given the error message you reported, either `event`` is not an instance of `Stripe::Event` or `Stripe::Event` does not define a `date` instance method.

Comment: One other though: The `stub...` RSpec methods are checking whether the class defines that method. I suspect `Stripe` is dynamically defining the `data` method, so you run into this. Try the revised version in my answer, which doesn't go through that "stubbing" check.

Comment: Ok this worked with regular `stub_chain`. BUT I had to define a `data` method in the class `Event`, otherwise it would still give me the error `Stripe::Event does not implement #data`. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Glad you got something working. Did you try it as I suggested it as well? Also, I agree with the the other answerer - the mock library seems like the way to go.

Comment: I didn't I probably will at some point, because I think the `stub_chain` is deprecating, but right now I just needed to get something out and I'm sadly still using deprecated terminology (e.g., `should`)

Answer (score 2):

In this given situation with Stripe, I'd choose mocking using a library instead of creating stubs with RSpec. I've used and would highly suggest [stripe-ruby-mock](https://github.com/rebelidealist/stripe-ruby-mock).

The benefit of this approach is that you're mocking more closely to how Stripe is actually working, and you can [switch to the actual stripe test api very easily](https://github.com/rebelidealist/stripe-ruby-mock#live-testing).